# How to extract something from text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a script providing information for some ip address.

I want to extract the country from the text.

in the following text country line is `"Country:        US"`

I want to display : `US` only

The text is:

```
[Querying whois.arin.net]
[whois.arin.net]
#
# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
#     "n 173.194.74.100"
#
# Use "?" to get help.
#

#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=173.194.74.100?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
CIDR:           173.194.0.0/16
OriginAS:       AS15169
NetName:        GOOGLE
NetHandle:      NET-173-194-0-0-1
Parent:         NET-173-0-0-0-0
NetType:        Direct Allocation
RegDate:        2009-08-17
Updated:        2012-02-24
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-173-194-0-0-1


OrgName:        Google Inc.
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US
RegDate:        2000-03-30
Updated:        2011-09-24
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/GOGL

OrgTechHandle: ZG39-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Google Inc
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgTechEmail:  arin-contact@google.com
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZG39-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: ZG39-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Google Inc
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgAbuseEmail:  arin-contact@google.com
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZG39-ARIN

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
```

Comment: I tried to split the string in array using separator ":" then use foreach -> then strpos

Comment: I want to get the country of ip addresses using exec('whois $ip') instead of get it from the sites which provide ip addresses api

Comment: split by "\n" character and then foreach -> split by ":"

Comment: It's better to do it using regex preg_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just the regex that you need - try this - the country id will be in the first group

```
Country:\s*([A-Z]{2})
```

- `Country:` - match literals
- `\s*` - match any number of whitespaces, tabs etc.
- `([A-Z]{2})` - match and capture any letter (uppercase) twice

use `preg_match_all` if you need all occurrences of this pattern

Comment: I tried your code but it get result for this ip only
but when try another ip it get empty result

Comment: @semsem - what do you mean ? Have you tried preg_match_all ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: @semsem - is the other example in any way different from this one ?

Comment: The problem was solved I added modifier /i to ignore case sensitive , because you wrote country with "C".
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

With preg_match you can do something like :

```
if (preg_match('/^Country:\s*([A-Z]{2,3)$/m', $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: It gives me result in this ip only but if i tried another one it don't match the country

Comment: Can you post the Country: ... part of the whois answer plz (or the IP) ?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding modifier /i :)
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

There is a [phpwhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) library for working with whois data.  It'll get you the response as an array.

Comment: Thank you for providing this library
I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Extract with preg_match

```
preg_match("/Country:(.*)\"/siU", $str, $match);
echo trim($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/country:[\ \t\r\n\f][A-Z]+\s/";

$txt = "descr: NCC#200X44704917
country: FR
admin-c: ACPSA223-RIPE
tech-c: TCWQQP8-RIPE";

preg_match($regex, $txt, $result);

print_r($result);
```

------------------------------------ 
Array ( [0] => country: FR )